# Spark SQL date conversion error from timestamp to string when using presto

Tags: apache-spark-sql, datetime-format, presto, date-format, presto-jdbc

I am trying to pull data from a table where the dates are in timestamp format 2019-06-31 19:00:00

I want to have them in string format as 20190631

It works if I choose get_pandas_df instead of get_spark_df but I need it in get_spark_df

I have tried this so far:

```
start_date = '2019-06-15'
end_date = '2019-06-31'
    
records = QaasHook.get_spark_df("""
            (SELECT name,
           cast(date_format(startdt, '%Y%m%d') AS VARCHAR) AS stdt,
           cast(amnt AS DOUBLE)                            AS amount,
           cast(date_format(enddt, '%Y%m%d') AS VARCHAR)   AS endt
    FROM   table_1
    WHERE  cast(date_format(startdt, '%Y%m%d') AS INT) >= {st_dt}
           AND cast(date_format(enddt, '%Y%m%d') AS INT) <= {end_dt} )
            """.format(st_dt = start_date.replace('-',''), end_dt = end_date.replace('-',''))
    )
```

But I get an error on the format line as

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-c72fafc06f37> in <module>
    159         where cast(date_format(cph.d_chkdate,'%Y%m%d') as int) >= {st_dt} and cast(date_format(cph.d_chkdate,'%Y%m%d') as int) <= {end_dt})
--> 160         """.format(st_dt = start_date.replace('-',''), end_dt = end_date.replace('-',''))
    161     )
    162 

/opt/pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dss_airflow_utils/hooks/qaas_hook.py in get_spark_df(self, dbtable, options)
    258             ", ".join(actual_options.keys()))
    259         spark_op = spark_op.options(**actual_options)
--> 260         return spark_op.load()
    261 
    262     def get_conn(self):

/opt/spark-3.0.0/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    182             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    183         else:
--> 184             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    185 
    186     @since(1.4)

/opt/spark-3.0.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/spark-3.0.0/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    129     def deco(*a, **kw):
    130         try:
--> 131             return f(*a, **kw)
    132         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    133             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/opt/spark-3.0.0/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o527.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: Error executing query
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoStatement.internalExecute(PrestoStatement.java:274)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoStatement.execute(PrestoStatement.java:227)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoPreparedStatement.<init>(PrestoPreparedStatement.java:80)
    at io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoConnection.prepareStatement(PrestoConnection.java:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: As far as Spark goes, datetime pattern in `format_date()` does not require `%` signs, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html. So you're probably getting strings like `%2019%06%31` which can't be cast to INT.

Comment: I am using Presto as well, and presto parses the dates with % signs.
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Comment: I see, I dont know then. Thanks for the ref!